# Printing Lists in Haskell new

Tags: list, haskell, printing

Brand new to haskell and I need to print out the data contained on a seperate row for each individual item

Unsure on how to

```
type ItemDescr = String
type ItemYear = Int
type ItemPrice = Int
type ItemSold = Int
type ItemSales = Int
type Item = (ItemRegion,ItemDescr,ItemYear,ItemPrice,ItemSold,ItemSales)
type ListItems = [Item]

rownumber x
 | x == 1  = ("Scotland","Desktop",2017,900,25,22500)
 | x == 2  = ("England","Laptop",2017,1100,75,82500)
 | x == 3  = ("Wales","Printer",2017,120,15,1800)
 | x == 4  = ("England","Printer",2017,120,60,7200)
 | x == 5  = ("England","Desktop",2017,900,50,45000)
 | x == 6  = ("Wales","Desktop",2017,900,20,18000)
 | x == 7  = ("Scotland","Printer",2017,25,25,3000)

showall
--print??
```

So for example on each individual line 
show

"Scotland","Desktop",2017,900,25,22500

followed by the next record

Comment: Seems like a homework question, within 24 hours someone asked a  question with a similar style of code . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402519/an-efficient-way-of-summing-up-different-values-in-a-haskell-database-implementa

Comment: @Elmex80s it’s definitely homework related but it”s not a duplicate, it’s asking about a different thing. Homework related questions aren’t per se banned on SO.

Comment: As to the asker: what have you tried so far? Do you know how to print other things?

Answer (score 0):

**Tip 1:**

Store the data like this

```
items = [("Scotland","Desktop",2017,900,25,22500),
         ("England","Laptop",2017,1100,75,82500),
         ("Wales","Printer",2017,120,15,1800),
         ("England","Printer",2017,120,60,7200),
         ("England","Desktop",2017,900,50,45000),
         ("Wales","Desktop",2017,900,20,18000),
         ("Scotland","Printer",2017,25,25,3000)]
```

**Tip 2:**

Implement this function

```
toString :: Item -> String
toString = undefined -- do this yourselves
```

**Tip 3:**

Try to combine the following functions

- `unlines`, already in the Prelude
- `toString`, you just wrote it
- `map`, does not need any explanation
- `putStrLn`, not even sure if this is a real function, but you need it anyway.
- `($)`, you can do without this one, but it will give you bonus points